# Javascript append fragment to an existing HTML element

Tags: javascript, fragment

I have created a DOM fragment where I am adding several childNodes in a loop:

```
fragment.appendChild( clone )
```

I want to take this fragment and use it to replace an existing HTML element that already contain those nodes.

I can use

```
myContainer.appendChild(fragment)
```

However this is done also in a loop and the fragment is appended too many times.
How can I get the fragment, append it to myContainer and delete also myContainer's old childs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
while (myContainer.childNodes.length > 0) {
    myContainer.removeChild(myContainer.childNodes[0]);
}

myContainer.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not append the Fragment after the loop has finished?

As for removing the current child nodes, you could cycle through them all and use the removeChild function, or you could just set the innerHTML of the element to an empty string. If you reset the innerHTML before you append the fragment it should be fine.

```
myContainer.innerHTML = "";
myContainer.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are creating a new node with some children, and you want this new node to replace an existing node in your page.

You can either:

- Remove all children of the existing node, and add the new children to the existing node
- Add all the children to another node (I think that is what you are doing: adding to the `fragment`), then remove the existing node, and add the node to that place.

See [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild)

Comment: myContainer.replaceChild(fragment, myOldElement) works only for one child. In my fragment and myOldElement I have multiple child nodes. i am looking for a way to use replaceChild() to replace multiple childrens with other elements at once... not just only one

Comment: @Mircea, you say you want something like a `replaceChild` that operates on arrays for instance? I am afraid there is none. You would have to call this in a loop.

Comment: yes something like replaceChild that can work not only for one child but for a collection of childs.